# object.prototype===object.fn history

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

### Calling all JS historians.

A common pattern is to alias a class' `prototype` to `fn`, which is less verbose.

Where did the `object.prototype===object.fn` convention originate in JavaScript?

I see *many* libraries using it.

Just curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this practice comes from original jQuery code where author wanted to shield developers from complexity (or natural beauty) of JavaScript native feature - prototypes.

Another potential reason could be the need to remove possible connotation [with existing PrototypeJS library] of the internal jQuery library prototype aspect.

Comment: It doesn't shield anyone from any complexity, though.  It's an alias, so they both do the same thing.

Comment: Yes, you are right, still I think the reason was to hide the potentially complex (how many libraries use prototype-oriented style?) concept of prototypes. May also be a way to remove "prototype" connotation from the all-new jQuery library (by the time this library appeared there was already popular PrototypeJS)